# Add current url as variable in CMS content

Tags: cms-block, variables

Is there a way to add current url in CMS content? Just like when I add the store name, something like this `{{config path="general/store_information/name"}}`

Answer (score 1):

you can add url like that,

```
{{store _direct="page_key"}}
```

Comment: But I need to add the current url, I don't know if it's possible with magento variables. eg.: I need to put the url `http://mystore.com/shoes/nike_shoes.html` in a url to create a share button to facebook, just like this `https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://mystore.com/shoes/nike_shoes.html`